# jScrollPane vertical scrollbar not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I've went into lots of questions here, but it seems I haven't found the solution I was looking for.
Here is the thing, I have an **ul** element with lots of **li**'s inside it. The **ul** is fixed height with the **li**'s going down and down. But when I use the jScrollPane in the **ul** element, it does not show the vertical scrollbar. Tried wrapping it inside another container with limited height and remove its limit, but it still doesn't work.
Any thing I can do?

```
<div id="city-scroll">  
    <ul class="cities">  
        <li><li>  
    </ul>  
</div>

<script>
    $('#city-scroll').jScrollPane();
</script>
```

That is my basic layout with a container (yes, the plugin call is within `$(document).ready(function(){...`).
The container is height limitted, the **ul** isn't. The **li**'s has fixed height and they **do** overflow the **div** height.

Answer (score 0):

did you define the css class?

```
#city-scroll {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Comment: Sure did, it works if I let its width smaller, but not height. It doesn't even create the `.jspVerticalBar` element.